# Optimising parameters for finding peaks in 1D array

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, data-analysis

I need to optimise a method for finding the number of data peaks in a 1D array. The data is a time-series of the amplitude of a wav file.

I have the code implemented already:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy.signal import find_peaks


_, amplitudes = read('audio1.wav')


indexes, _ = find_peaks(amplitudes, height=80)
print(f'Number of peaks: {len(indexes)}')
```

When plotted, the data looks like this:

[General scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVaVQ.png)

The 'peaks' that I am interested in are clear to the human eye - there are 23 in this particular dataset.

However, because the array is so large, the data is extremely variant within the peaks that are clear at a general scale (hence the many hundreds of peaks labelled with blue crosses):

[Zoomed in view of one peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74qsp.png)

Peak-finding questions have been asked many times before (I've been through a lot of them!) - but I can't find any help or explanation of **optimising the parameters** for finding only the peaks I want. I know a little about Python, but am blind when it comes to mathematical analysis!

Analysing by width seems useless because, as per the second image, the peaks clear at a large scale are actually interspersed with 'silent' ranges. Distance is not helpful because I do not know how close the peaks will be in other wav files. Prominence has been suggested as the best method but I could not get the results I needed; threshold likewise. I have also tried decimating the signal, smoothing the signal with a Savitzky-Golay filter, and different combinations of parameters and values, all with inaccurate results.

Height alone has been useful because I can see from the charts that peaks always reach above 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common task in audio processing and there are several approaches which totally depend on your data.

However, there are implementations out there which are used for finding peaks in novelty functions (e.g., the output from a beat tracker). Try these ones:

- https://madmom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/features/onsets.html#madmom.features.onsets.peak_picking
- https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.util.peak_pick.html#librosa.util.peak_pick

Basically they implement the same method but there might be differences in the details.
Furthermore, you could check, if you really need to work on this high sampling frequency. Try downsampling the signal or use a moving average filter.

Answer (score 1):

Look at *0d persistent homology* to find a good strategy, where the parameter you can optimize for is *peak persistence*. A nice blog post [here](https://www.sthu.org/blog/13-perstopology-peakdetection/index.html) explains the basics.

But in short the idea is to imagine your graph being filled by water, and then slowly draining the water. Every time a piece of the graph comes above water a new island is born. When two islands are next to each other they merge, which causes the younger island (with the lower peak) to die.
Then each data point has a birth time and a death time. The most significant peaks are those with the longest *persistence*, which is `death - birth`.

If the water level drops at a continuous rate, then the persistence is defined in terms of peak height. Another possibility is by dropping the water instantaneously from point to point as time goes from step `t` to step `t+1`, in wich case the persistence is defined in peak *width* in terms of signal samples.

For you it seems that using the original definition in terms of peak height > 70 finds all peaks you are interested in, albeit possibly too many, clustered together. You can limit this by choosing the first peak in each cluster or the highest peak in each cluster or by doing both approaches and only choosing peaks that have both great height persistence as well as width persistence.